# Alterar background do Botão

Tags: java, android, android-layout

Como posso fazer para alterar o *background* de um `Button` ao clicar nele? Por exemplo: eu tenho o `shape01` e o `shape02`, por *default* o `Button` esta com o `shape01`, ao clicar nele preciso mudar para o `shape02`, e ao clicar novamente retornar para o `shape01`.

Answer (score 1):

Você precisa criar um **Selector** e coloca-lo como **background** do botão.

Exemplo:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:enterFadeDuration="@android:integer/config_shortAnimTime"
    android:exitFadeDuration="@android:integer/config_shortAnimTime">

    <item android:state_checked="true" android:color="@color/white" />
    <item android:state_pressed="true" android:color="@color/white" />
    <item android:state_enabled="false"  android:color="@color/colorAccent" />
    <item android:color="@color/colorAccent" />

</selector>
```

Comment: Obrigado pela ajuda, mas acabo de ver mais algumas coisas que vou ter q fazer aqui. Entao como poderia fazer essa mudanca usando swit?

Comment: O que seria swit?

Answer (score 1):

Primeiro crie os shapes:
Shape do Botão (normal):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

        <gradient
            android:angle="270"
            android:startColor="#2e8fc2"
            android:endColor="#006599"
            />

        <stroke
            android:width="2dp"
            android:color="#00679e"
            />

        <corners
            android:radius="3dp"
            />

</shape>
```

E depois do botão quando estiver pressionado:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">

    <gradient
        android:angle="270"
        android:startColor="#254683"
        android:endColor="#1f2f61"
        />

    <stroke
        android:color="#000000"
        android:width="2dp"
        />

    <corners
        android:radius="3dp"
        />

</shape>
```

E depois, crie um selector:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item
        android:state_pressed="true"
        android:drawable="@drawable/botao_seleccionado"
        />

    <item
        android:drawable="@drawable/botao"
        />

</selector>
```

E por último, vá ao código (.xml) do botão que vai receber esses backgrounds e adicione o seguinte:

```
android:background="@drawable/seleccionador"
```

Answer (score 0):

Programaticamente você pode usar uma *flag*. Então pode declarar por exemplo, `colorFlag = 0`. Assim você pode definir a cor usando `setBackgroundColor()`. Toda vez que você mudar clicar, poderá mudar uma cor diferente. Se preferir também, você pode colocar quantas cores quiser no momento do clique.

#### Main.java

```
public class Main extends Activity {

    private Button btn;
    private int colorFlag = 0;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                if (colorFlag == 0) {
                    btn.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#00ff00")); // verde
                    colorFlag = 1;
                } else {
                    btn.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#ffff00")); // amarelo
                    colorFlag = 0;
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

#### main.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:background="#ffff00"
        android:text="Button" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

#### Screenshots

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Tente

```
int color = 0x8000FF00; // 50% verde
Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnTeste);

button.getBackground().setColorFilter(color, PorterDuff.Mode.MULTIPLY);
```

O resultado é muito bom e você não perde o desenho original do botão.

Answer (score 0):

Para mudar o ícone do botão da minha aplicação eu usei esse código.

```
if(mp.isPlaying()==true) {
                bTocar.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.play);

            }else{                   
                bTocar.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.pause);
            }
```